# ANSI C - Appending nodes to arbitrary tree

Tags: c, struct, tree

When appending a new node to an arbitrary tree, would you traverse the tree from the root?  Or would you build subtrees and combine them to build a whole tree?

My Node and Tree structures look like:

**Node.h**

```
struct _Node;
typedef struct _Node Node;
```

**Node.c**

```
struct _Node
{
    char *pName;
    unsigned char *pValue;
    struct _Node *pFirstChild;
    struct _Node *pNextSibling;
};

Node* NodeCreate(char *pName, uint32_t uLength, unsigned char *pValue)
{
    if (!pValue)
        return NULL;

    Node *pNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!pNode)
        return NULL;

    pNode->pName = pName;
    pNode->pValue = (unsigned char*)malloc(uLength * sizeof(pValue[0]));
    pNode->pFirstChild = NULL;
    pNode->pNextSibling = NULL;

    return pNode;
}
```

**Tree.h**

```
struct _Tree;
typedef struct _Tree Tree;
```

**Tree.c**

```
struct _Tree
{
    Node *pRoot;
};

Node* TreeNodeCreate(char *pName, uint32_t uLength, unsigned char *pValue)
{
    return NodeCreate(pName, uLength, pValue);
}

Node* TreeNodeAppend(Node **ppParent, Node *pNode)
{
    if (!((*ppParent)->pFirstChild))
    {
        (*ppParent)->pFirstChild = pNode;

        return (*ppParent)->pFirstChild;
    }

    Node *pLastChild = (*ppParent)->pFirstChild;
    while (pLastChild->pNextSibling)
        pLastChild = pLastChild->pNextSibling;

    pLastChild->pNextSibling = pNode;

    return pLastChild;
}

Node* TreeGetRoot(Tree *pTree)
{
    if (!pTree)
        return NULL;

    return pTree->pRoot;
}

void TreeSetRoot(Tree **ppTree, Node *pNode)
{
    (*ppTree)->pRoot = pNode;
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char value[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    uint32_t uLength = sizeof(value) / sizeof(value[0]);

    Tree *pTree = TreeCreate();

    Node *pRoot = TreeNodeCreate("Root", uLength, value);
    TreeSetRoot(&pTree, pRoot); 

    Node *pA = TreeNodeCreate("A", uLength, value);
    Node *pB = TreeNodeCreate("B", uLength, value);
    Node *pC = TreeNodeCreate("C", uLength, value);
    Node *pD = TreeNodeCreate("D", uLength, value);
    Node *pE = TreeNodeCreate("E", uLength, value);
    Node *pF = TreeNodeCreate("F", uLength, value);

    TreeNodeAppend(&pRoot, pA);
    TreeNodeAppend(&pRoot, pB);

    TreeNodeAppend(&pA, pC);
    TreeNodeAppend(&pA, pD);

    TreeNodeAppend(&pB, pE);
    TreeNodeAppend(&pE, pF);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using a `pName` field in your code, but I don't see such field in your node declaration.

Comment: @anatolyg-Please see my edit.  I'm not sure about my TreeNodeCreate() function.  I mean is it Tree's job to create a new node?

Comment: @AndreyT-I've corrected my code.  I'd like to know a proper way to append a new node to an arbitrary tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on how your tree is organized. "Arbitrary tree", and you using an arbitrary number of child nodes is not generally used for something where nodes have a determined order; in most cases, such trees appear when the parent/child relationship is the thing that's important.

In such cases, your append would generally be more like "add this node as a child for that parent", allow a quick insert since the parent is already known, and a constant time insert if the order of the children doesn't matter.

Otherwise, you might have to go through the tree following whatever rules your application has to find the correct location to place the node.

Comment: @ChristianStieber-In my case, parent/child relationship is important and the order of children doesn’t matter.  Please see my code above.  Would you do something similar?  I’m not sure whether or not creating two structures is better than simply using the Node structure to achieve the same thing.